# Reason for two similar codes giving different result and different approaches to this task

Tags: python

The question is

```
def sum_numbers_in_file(filename):
    """
    Return the sum of the numbers in the given file (which only contains
    integers separated by whitespace).
    >>> sum_numbers_in_file("numbers.txt")
    19138
    """
```

this is my first code:

```
rtotal = 0
myfile = open(filename,"r")
num = myfile.readline()
num_list = []

while num:
    number_line = ""
    number_line += (num[:-1])
    num_list.append(number_line.split(" "))
    num = myfile.readline()
for item in num_list:
    for item2 in item:
        if item2!='':
            rtotal+= int(item2)
return rtotal
```

this is my second code:

```
f = open(filename)
m = f.readline()
n = sum([sum([int(x) for x in line.split()]) for line in f])
f.close()
return n
```

however the first one returns 19138 and the second one 18138

numbers.txt contains the following:

```
1000 
15000 
2000 
1138
```

Comment: Just a comment about your approach.  The question indicates integers separated by 'whitespace', whereas your implementation assumes newlines.  You may wish to read in the whole file first, then split by '\r\n ', or use regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that `m = f.readline()` in the second snippet skips the first line (which contains `1000`), that's why you get a wrong result.

Answer (score 4):

Because `m = f.readLine()` already reads 1 line from f and then you do the operation with the rest of the lines. If you delete that statement the 2 outputs will be the same. (I think :))

Answer (score 2):

As requested.. another approach to the question:

```
import re

def sum(filename):
  return sum(int(x.group()) for x in re.finditer(r'\d+',open(filename).read()))
```

Answer (score 1):

As said by answers, you are skipping first line because f.readline(). But a shorter approach would be:

```
n=sum((int(line[:-1]) for line in open("numbers.txt") if line[0].isnumeric()))
```

Comment: Doesn't fulfill the brief. Would break if there were multiple (whitespace separated) numbers per line. Also slicing off the last character in a line isn't very useful when EOL marker is more than one character. Conveniently, however, `int` is forgiving about leading and trailing whitespace.